# How to use PCA algorithm for feature reduction in matlab...?

Tags: matlab, pca, feature-selection, dimensionality-reduction

I am new at this method and I just want to get a solution with in a short time period.. So please help me how can I implement this method effectively.. For example, we have 10 sample set each having 10 images and each image having 1*576 so, we have extracted 10 sample set feature size. i.e 100*576 so I just want to reduce it 576 to 250.

I applied `[coeff, score, latent, tsquared, mu]=pca(x,'Numcomponents',inf);` but I did not get the right output that means reduced feature, it is not working and getting trouble to select which one is the final output from this method..
Here anyone can help me to solve this...

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question with sufficient and specific information to describe your problem.

Comment: Basic singular vector decomposition `[U,S,V] = svd(x, 'econ');` has less output parameters, but it's the same PCA.